# Correct way of designing Android Model Classes

Tags: android, class, model

I am developing an Android application where I have to fetch data from server through Rest APIs. I am in start of project and have to design my model classes for handling data. I am confused to create a Model class in an effective way. I have to handle events data. Events are of different type like upcoming,attended and waiting for approval etc all events have 70% same data but few different tags according to event type. How should I model events. Do I create one big model including all tags of events or I should create separate model for each event type. I need a suggestion for better implementation. Please help. Thanks

Comment: And the answer is going to be-  it entirely depends on what you want to do in detail with the data.  We just don't have enough data to answer here.

Comment: I would suggest you to create separate model for each event type. Helps in modularity.

Answer (score 0):

you can used common modul class and add common setter and getter method in one model class.different variables for different use then you can used separate model for each event type.